# How can I the value from JSP Page with JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl

```
<%
    com.BeanPaket.kontrolBean kontrol = new kontrolBean();
    String epostavalue = kontrol.getEposta();
%>

<sql:query var="kutuphane" dataSource="${dataSource}">
    SELECT * FROM kutuphane.odunc_kitaplar WHERE eposta = ?

</sql:query>
```

How can I put the value that I recognized in <% %> tag into the sql query for getting the list from database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<sql:query var="kutuphane" dataSource="${dataSource}">
SELECT * FROM kutuphane.odunc_kitaplar WHERE eposta = ?
   <sql:param value="${epostavalue}" />
</sql:query>
```

Comment: Ok I solved the problem without using <sql:param> tag. We can also use this code ; WHERE eposta ='<%=epostaval%>

Comment: Use parameterized query with sql:param and don't use direct query (<%= ... =>). It can be vulnerable.